# Import error: cannot import arff under workon condition

Tags: python, virtualenv, arff

I create a virtualenvs under the name py4all. And I install scipy, numpy, and liac-arff.

When I enter py4all using cd ~/.virtualenvs/py4all, I use python and I can import arff.

When I call py4all using workon, I cannot import arff. But using the same method, I can import scipy and numpy.

I enter py4all using cd ~/.virtualenvs/py4all, and trying to install arff, the system shows

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): liac-arff in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I understand that I can use arff without using workon, but my numpy and scipy is install in py4all and not the system python. What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to prepare new virtualenv:

1. Create a new virtual environment;
2. Activate this new virtual environment, either using `workon` (if you use a wrapper) or activation script;
3. Install desired packages, i.e. `pip install`;
4. Decativate the environment.

Now, when you'll want to use the packages from the created environment:

1. Activate this new virtual environment, either using `workon` or activation script;
2. Import desired packages in interactive shell or your script;
3. Deactivate the environment when done.

In your particular case, if scipy and numpy are already installed in the environment, then just activate it and install liac-arff there. After this, everytime you'll use (import) this packages, when the environment is active, python will use the packages from the environment instead of the system's python packages.

Comment: I try to install the liac-arff package in the virtualenvs, py4all, again but it keep showing

Comment: "already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): liac-arff in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" I enter the python/site-packages but there is no liac-arff packages. So I assume the package is install in the system python2.7. How can I overcome this issue? Can I copy the packages from system python into the py4all/lib/python2.7/site-packages?

Comment: @pill45, liac-arff is installed in system python - look at the path in the message. Also, it looks like your virtualenv has access to system's site-packages. Try: `pip uninstall liac-arff`, when NOT in virtualenv, to remove it from system python. Then activate the virtualenv and do `pip install liac-arff` to install it inside the virtualenv.

Comment: @pill45 Note, that you need to activate the environment via activation script (e.g. `source ~/.virtualenvs/py4all/bin/activate` or `. ~/.virtualenvs/py4all/bin/activate`) or `workon py4all` command, not just `cd` to it's directory (unless you got hooks installed), or specify virtualenv's pip explicitly, e.g.  `~/.virtualenvs/py4all/bin/pip install liac-arff`.